# can i use window application vb dll in .net webapplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb6

i am trying to use vb 6.0 dll which is for window application in .net webapplication
so tell me can i use it if yes then please tell me how

Answer (score 1):

As long as the dll does not show any UI, this should not be a problem.

Using Visual Studio, you can add a reference to the dll via the COM tab.

If you are using .Net 4.0, you should [read this.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/samng/archive/2009/06/16/com-interop-in-c-4-0.aspx) For older versions, read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163494.aspx).